# Access inner element from within an element in protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, pageobjects

I came across concept of Page Objects, and used it in writing tests in Protractor, but I am facing an issue. The old code was as follows.

```
var productList = element.all(by.repeater('product in contractsCtrl.contracts'));
productList.get(0).element(by.model('qty')).sendKeys(20);
```

I organized the code in  a class, like

```
var Product = {
  productList : element.all(by.repeater('product in contractsCtrl.contracts')),
  qtyElem : element(by.model('qty')),
  setProduct : function (pos) {
     this.productElem = this.productList.get(pos);
  }
}
```

Now to implement the scenario (as in code snippet 1) with Page Objects, I modified code as,

```
 var Product = require('product.js');
 Product.setProduct(0);
```

I am stuck here on how to access the `qtyElem` within `productElem`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a method `setProductQty()`, which sets quantity for a product on specific position:

```
var Product = {

    productList : element.all(by.repeater('product in contractsCtrl.contracts')),

    setProductQty: function (pos, qty) {
        var productElem = this.productList.get(pos);
        productElem.element(by.model('qty')).sendKeys(qty);
        return this;
    }

};
```

And usage will look like:

```
var Product = require('product.js');
Product.setProductQty(0, 20);
// ---product index---^
// --------quantity-------^
```

This method describes a single action which user usually performs at a time: he sees a product at position and sets a quantity. You can take it as a rule when designing Page Objects - try to define what is a single user action for particular situation and make a method for it.